# Mac Wireless Mouse, not apple brand

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, hardware-recommendation

Which mouse is able connect to MBP 2011, But not apple brand.
I'm looking for mouse that can connect without need to use the USB port permanently.

Comment: Every BT mouse works. Personally I use a Microsoft laptop mouse as they manufacture high quality consumer input devices.

Comment: @MaxRied Can it work without use of their bluettooth wireless?

Comment: If you buy a bluetooth mouse, they work with your MB's integrated bluetooth module.

Comment: @MaxRied Thank you mac, can you please write your answer on "Answer section" so i can approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect any Bluetooth mouse to your MB's integrated bluetooth module. Personally I'd recommend Microsoft mice as they are of good quality. My father recently had some problems with a el cheapo china model, but if you pick a brand, you should not have a problem.

Make sure it has this logo on it, and not some "Yeah we do our own kewl 2.5 GHz radio" (actually there is no reason to do this, except not to pay a few cents for the Bluetooth license):
[image]

Comment: There is a reason, actually: the other stuff often has better battery life because it is a one-way (i.e. no receiver in the keyboard) protocol rather than two-way. However, this also means inferior security (Bluetooth exchanges encryption keys during pairing), so I wouldn't recommend it, though this is less of an issue for mice rather than keyboards.

Comment: @KevinReid My BT mouse runs now for over one year without changing the batteries, while my elcheapo Trust mouse with proprietary receiver lasted a week on it's best times.